# How can I access the int values of an object in an NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I try to access some values in a NSMutableArray I created, but I only get some numbers (address?) if I try to access them.

I was able to initialize an array and can add and change objects with

```
[myNSMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]]
```

and

```
[myNSMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:47]
```

I also can print the value at index [0] with

```
NSLog(@"%@", [myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

and I get `47` as expected.

But how can I access the integer value of the object in the array so I can save it to`myIntValue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int myIntValue = [[myNSMutableArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
```

Just have a look at the [NSNumber class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)